# space (slots) optimization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'll start directly with the example:

In a game, there is a bag that players will use to store their items (items has variable sizes) and the bag has a variable size also.

In a bag of 8x15 slots, I need to insert an item that occupies 2x2 slots, I can search space to actually check if there's enough space for this item to be stored - this is easy, but, what if I don't have enough space to store the requested item? This is the real problem.

I'm trying to find a way to actually rearranging all the current items in the current bag in order to release space for the new item.

Is there any algorithm that will help me doing that?

## EDIT

Rules:

1. I cannot remove any of the current items in the bag, just rearrange them in order to store a new one if there's not enough space.

Comment: Bad news: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @Jochen this isn't the knapsack problem, because we're not trying to get a maximal subset, we're trying to decide of a particular set will fit into a given container.

Comment: What shapes and sizes can individual items be?  If they are constrained the problem becomes that much easier.

Comment: @bdares Actually I have some variable sizes, 1x1, 1x2, 1x4, 2x2, 2x4, 3x3, 4x3, but this can change.

Comment: I haven't got an algorithm handy, but I would be writing one to go largest to smallest and work from there. You can always find a slot to drop a 1x1 item in, but going with a 5x2 item last might be much more challenging.

Comment: @bdares Then I misunderstood the question. OP said "what if I don't have enough space ...". To me that seemed to ask for the maximum subset of stuff that can fit. And even if that's not the question, intuitively, arranging the items is a very similar problem.

Comment: @Jochen The reorganization will execute only if I don't find enough space to store the current item.

Comment: @erisco all items are teorically rectangular: each "slot" is a square of 1x1, and those items can use one (1x1) or more slots... the maximum number of items are the width of the bag * the height of the bag, in the case of 8x15, 120 items with 1x1 size.

Comment: @Jochen It looks like a different problem to me because in the knapsack problem the ordering is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this unfortunately is an NP-hard problem, but you can use a greedy approximation algorithm. The approximation algorithm could work as follows:

- Sort all items by item volume, descending.
- Iterate trough the list and try to place the current item anywhere
- If at any point the current item can't be fitted anywhere, decide that the item can't be picked up.
- If all pieces are fitted, decide that the item can be picked up.

This is based on the intuitive thought that larger pieces are 'harder' to place than smaller pieces. Another thing you could do, if most items are 1x1, is a brute-force solution, which is quite feasible in such a small inventory. This would work as follows:

- Try every single position for the current piece, where it still fits and for every such position:
- Do this with the next unpositioned piece.

This will always solve your problem, but is way slower (though more accurate). This algorithm can be inproved by leaving out every 1x1 piece, placing them afterwards.

Comment: One could also use a search technique such as backtracking instead of brute-force search. With good heuristics, such methods can often find a solution (if one exists) much faster than the simple enumeration methods, although they are equally slow at proving that no solution exists.

Comment: I know its been a long time, but I've managed to solve this by using genetic algorithms ;)